# Conditional setting of li element class with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, menuitem

I have a simple menu in /Shared/MainMenu.cshtml:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Features", "Index", "Features", "active")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Faq", "Index", "Faq")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Index", "Help")</li>
  </ul>
```

I want to indicate the current page but setting a value in the Index.cshtml and have that set the class of the relevant

element to "active", just as the "Home" menu item has, above.

What is the simplest way to set the class of the relevant

without setting the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe?

```
@{
    String controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="@(controller == "Home" ? "active": "")">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
    <li class="@(controller == "Features" ? "active": "")">@Html.ActionLink("Features", "Index", "Features", "active")</li>
    <li class="@(controller == "Faq" ? "active": "")">@Html.ActionLink("Faq", "Index", "Faq")</li>
    <li class="@(controller == "Help" ? "active": "")">@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Index", "Help")</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Ooh nice, thanks! I was almost there but I think I was missing the brackets. D'oh!

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` does not exist anymore in ASP.NET Core; Use `IHttpContextAccessor` instead;